# How to specify SMS URL for specific text message

Tags: twilio-api

Is there a way when using the REST API to send an outgoing message that I can specify the SMS Url to use for any responses to that message? I saw mention of it in the docs where it says you can specify it for the phone number in the console or via the API.  If I post a variable named SmsUrl when sending the text it still uses the url connected to the number or the twilio app.

We need responses to submit back to a url on our server that includes a parameter that lets us connect the response to a specific inspection request. In other words we need to be able to connect the response not to the from number but to the record on our end for which the outgoing message was triggered.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending from a single number this is totally impossible, SMS simply doesn't work like that. If you send me 5 SMS and then I reply to one of them my reply contains no data which links it to the SMS I am responding to.

The only ways I can see you achieving this are:

- Assign a different outgoing number to each trigger. This is foolproof
  but may not be viable depending on your usecase and nuber of 
  triggers. It may also confuse your users if they get texts from many 
  different numbers, although if you buy consecutive ones you could
  mitigate this.
- Include instructions in your SMS like "Reply 1 to request a call, 2 
  to request a password reset..." or "Start your reply with XXXX" where
  XXXX is a unique code you generate server side and assign to the 
  user, or have a code for each trigger or whatever. This would work
  with only one outgoing number, but in my experience the end users 
  will screw it up a lot of the time and not respect your instructions.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid of that. Also tried cookies but they only work after the first response is posted back to the sms url. For now I am just looking up the from number to match it to at least the inspector that sent it. It would be ideal if twilio could store just one value passed to the API when the outgoing message is sent and then pass that back the way they would cookies

Comment: Reading it again I'm not sure I properly understood your question. When you say "that I can specify the SMS Url to use for any responses to that message?" by responses do you mean SMS responses from the person you sent the SMS to, or status responses about your sent message from Twilio?

Comment: I mean sms responses from the person we sent the text to

Comment: OK, in that case I stand by my original answer. I thought of a hacky workaround for this a while back - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45178678/twilio-messaging-correlating-sid/45178984#45178984